# Iterating over a vector and calling a function in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector having 5 elements and I want to call a function `foo` for each of these elements.
Here is the example -

```
foo <- function(printMe)
{
   print(printMe)
}

vec <- c("Hello", "How are you?", "Take Care", "Welcome", "Goodbye")
```

What should be the best way to call the function `foo` for each element of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is vectorised (like in this example) you can pass the vector directly in the function.

```
foo(vec)
```

If your function is not vectorised meaning it can handle only one input at a given time, you can use any of the looping method available.

```
#1. for loop
for(i in vec) {
  foo(i)
}

#2. sapply/lapply
sapply(vec, foo)
lapply(vec, foo)

#3. purrr::map
purrr::map(vec, foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function `Vectorize()` in R to do this, so you can just do:

```
Vectorize(foo)(vec)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing a base R function. Much better than using for loop.